# 'La operación no es válida mientras ItemsSource esté en uso. Obtenga acceso y modifique los elementos con ItemsControl.ItemsSource.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

llevo toda la tarde comiendome la cabeza con esto y me gustaría que alguien fuera tan amable de poder solventarmelo.
Estoy cargando en un DataGrid de WPF una colección con ItemSource con un evento al pulsar un botón, la cosa es que cuando quiero añadir un elemento nuevo al DataGrid, me salta esa excepción y no se muy bien como solventarla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estos son los dos métodos juntos, el que carga con el ItemSource y el que intenta añadir un elemento a la lista con Items.Add():
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias de antemano

Actualización:
Vale, al final he conseguido que funcione después de un golpe de inspiración divina añadiendo los objetos a una lista y luego actualizando el datagrid con los elementos de la lista cada vez que se le añadiera uno nuevo, el codigo quedaría así:

```
private void bVer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Libros li = fich.obtenerLibros("almacenLibros.xml");
        listaLibros = li.libros;
        dgLibros.ItemsSource = listaLibros;            
    }

    private void bAñadirLibro_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Libro li = new Libro();
        li.autor = tbAutor.Text;
        li.codigo = Convert.ToInt32(tbCodigo.Text);
        li.descripcion = tbDescripcion.Text;
        li.isbn = Convert.ToInt32(tbISBN.Text);
        li.numEjemplares = Convert.ToInt32(tbNEjemplares.Text);
        li.titulo = tbTitulo.Text;                        
        listaLibros.Add(li);
        dgLibros.ItemsSource = listaLibros;
        dgLibros.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Sube el código directamente en lugar de una imagen para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: He actualizado en la pregunta lo que he hecho, igualmente muchas gracias por la ayuda ^^

Comment: Que bueno que encontraras una solución, en cierto casos también vale asignar el Source como null, agregar el item a la lista y asignar el Source nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `ItemsSource` esta siendo utilizada por la coleccion `listaLibros` por lo que deberias de agregar el elemento a esa coleccion, en vez de reasignarsela a la propiedad.

```
private void bAñadirLibro_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Libro li = new Libro();
    li.autor = tbAutor.Text;
    // ...
    listaLibros.Add(li); // solo agregas la propiedad a la lista de libros y no lo reasignas a ItemsSource
}
```

---

Si no se visualiza el nuevo elemento en la lista al agregarlo, probable que sea debido a que la coleccion debe de ser de tipo `ObservableCollection<Libro>`.